# getting median of particular rows of array based on index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays of the same length, one containing an index and the other containing its corresponding value i.e. one index can have more than one value:

```
idx = [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5...]
values = [1.2,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.3,1.2,3.3,4.1,5.4...]
```

I want to return an array which holds the unique index as well as the median value for objects with the same idx value.

e.g.

```
result = 
    [0, np.median([1.2,3.1,3.1])
     1, np.median([3.1,3.3,1.2])
     2, etc. ]
```

My brute force approach is to just go:

```
for idxi in np.arange(np.max(idx)):
    mask = (idxi == idx)
    medians = np.median(values[mask])
    result.append([idxi,medians])
```

This is far to slow for my needs unfortunately and quite ugly in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind a dependency on `scipy`, the function [`scipy.ndimage.labeled_comprehension`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.labeled_comprehension.html) can do this.  Here's an example.

First set up the sample data:

```
In [570]: import numpy as np

In [571]: idx = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5])

In [572]: values = np.array([1.2,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.3,1.2,3.3,4.1,5.4,6,6,6.2,6,7,7.2,7.2])
```

Get the unique "labels" in `idx`.  (If you already know the maximum is, say, `N`, and you know that all the integers from 0 to `N` are used, you could use `uniq = range(N+1)` instead.)

```
In [573]: uniq = np.unique(idx)  # Or range(idx.max()+1)

In [574]: uniq
Out[574]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Use `labeled_comprehension` to compute the median of each labeled group:

```
In [575]: from scipy.ndimage import labeled_comprehension

In [576]: medians = labeled_comprehension(values, idx, uniq, np.median, np.float64, None)

In [577]: medians
Out[577]: array([ 3.1,  3.1,  4.1,  6. ,  6.5,  7.2])
```

---

Another option, if you don't mind the dependency on [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/), is to use the `groupby` function of the `pandas.DataFrame` class.

Set up the DataFrame:

```
In [609]: import pandas as pd

In [610]: df = pd.DataFrame(dict(labels=idx, values=values))

In [611]: df
Out[611]: 
    labels  values
0        0     1.2
1        0     3.1
2        0     3.1
3        1     3.1
4        1     3.3
5        1     1.2
6        2     3.3
7        2     4.1
8        2     5.4
9        3     6.0
10       3     6.0
11       3     6.2
12       4     6.0
13       4     7.0
14       5     7.2
15       5     7.2
```

Use `groupby` to group the data uses the `labels` column, and then compute the medians of the groups:

```
In [612]: result = df.groupby('labels').median()

In [613]: result
Out[613]: 
        values
labels        
0          3.1
1          3.1
2          4.1
3          6.0
4          6.5
5          7.2
```

---

Disclaimer: I haven't tried either of those suggestions on large arrays, so I don't know how their performance will compare with your brute force solution or with @Ashwini's answer.

Comment: Minor: `median` is a method of groupby objects, so `df.groupby("labels").median()` will work too.

Answer (score 2):

For the idx array you can get the unique items using `numpy.unique`, and to get the corresponding values from the other array we can use `numpy.diff` with `numpy.where` to get indices where the items change. Using these indices we can split the values array using `numpy.array_split` and then apply `np.mean` on its items:

```
>>> idx = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5])
>>> values = np.array([1.2,3.1,3.1,3.1,3.3,1.2,3.3,4.1,5.4] + [1]*7)
>>> indices = np.where(np.diff(idx) != 0)[0] + 1
>>> map(np.mean, np.array_split(values, indices))
[2.4666666666666668, 2.5333333333333337, 4.2666666666666666, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
>>> np.unique(idx)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> np.dstack((_, __))[0]
array([[ 0.        ,  2.46666667],
       [ 1.        ,  2.53333333],
       [ 2.        ,  4.26666667],
       [ 3.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 4.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 5.        ,  1.        ]])
```

Comment: This would only work if the idx values are in sequential order  and grouped together right (i.e. [0,0,0,1,1,1...] not [0,1,2,0,1...])? Could this be made to work for any ordering of idx values? I made my example too specific, sorry.

Comment: @Griff If they are not sequential then we can sort them first and sort corresponding values as well(using `numpy.argsort`). This would make it `O(N log N)` in complexity, though we can still do this in `O(N) `time in pure Python, but the excessive for-loops may slow things down.